# EF Core database connection kept active

Tags: database, postgresql, entity-framework-core, connection

I have an .Net Core application using EF Core with postgres. While the application is running, IF I run

```
docker exec -i postgres-db  psql -U admin eventsDb --command "select pid as process_id,        usename as username,        datname as database_name,  client_addr as client_address,  application_name,  backend_start, state, state_changefrom pg_stat_activity";
```

There are 7 processes running:

```
 pid | username | database_name | client_address | application_name |         backend_start         | state  |         state_change
-----+----------+---------------+----------------+------------------+-------------------------------+--------+-------------------------------
  33 |          |               |                |                  | 2021-04-15 14:10:43.496459+00 |        |
  35 | admin    |               |                |                  | 2021-04-15 14:10:43.497432+00 |        |
 232 | admin    | eventsDb      | 172.18.0.1     |                  | 2021-04-15 14:27:21.61369+00  | idle   | 2021-04-15 14:27:21.675184+00
 246 | admin    | eventsDb      |                | psql             | 2021-04-15 14:27:38.210868+00 | active | 2021-04-15 14:27:38.216957+00
  31 |          |               |                |                  | 2021-04-15 14:10:43.495634+00 |        |
  30 |          |               |                |                  | 2021-04-15 14:10:43.494741+00 |        |
  32 |          |               |                |                  | 2021-04-15 14:10:43.496089+00 |        |
(7 rows)
```

If I stop the application has 6 processes:

```
$ docker exec -i postgres-db  psql -U admin eventsDb --command "select pid,        usename as username,        datname as database_name,  client_addr as client_address,  application_name,  backend_start, state, state_change from pg_stat_activity";
 pid | username | database_name | client_address | application_name |         backend_start         | state  |         state_change
-----+----------+---------------+----------------+------------------+-------------------------------+--------+-------------------------------
  33 |          |               |                |                  | 2021-04-15 14:10:43.496459+00 |        |
  35 | admin    |               |                |                  | 2021-04-15 14:10:43.497432+00 |        |
 261 | admin    | eventsDb      |                | psql             | 2021-04-15 14:28:10.544338+00 | active | 2021-04-15 14:28:10.546737+00
  31 |          |               |                |                  | 2021-04-15 14:10:43.495634+00 |        |
  30 |          |               |                |                  | 2021-04-15 14:10:43.494741+00 |        |
  32 |          |               |                |                  | 2021-04-15 14:10:43.496089+00 |        |
(6 rows)
```

The connection string is:

```
"Host=localhost;Username=admin;Password=<password>;Database=eventsDb;"
```

The question is:
Is this the normal behavior for EF Core when no database IO operation performed?

Comment: Are you disposing your DbContext(s)? The answer to this behaviour will be linked to how you are declaring/providing your DbContext instances.

Comment: services.AddDbContext<EventDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")
                )); this is how DbContext is registered.